# I cant write this factorial codes

Tags: c, factorial

I have some problem with that. I am trying to learn C programming. Please help me

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int a, factorial;

    printf("Please enter a value :" );

    scanf("%d", &a);


    for (int i = 1; i<=a; i++) 
    {
        a = (a - 1)*a;
    }
    printf("%d", factorial);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int factorial = 1;` and then `factorial *= i;` inside the loop. But I think you should have stated what your problem is. You could have for example looked on the internet for an implementation and force yourself to look for differences and understand why there are differences.

Comment: check the returned value (not the parameter value from the call to `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: should check that the user entered value is > 0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your code line `a = (a - 1)*a;` you actually changed your input for getting the factorial. It also will blow your loop. See your for loop will continue as long as your `i` is less than `a`, lets say you choose `a=3` after first iteration the `a` itself will become `6`, so the for loop will continue until it reach the integer limit and you will get overflow error.

**What you should do?**

First of all you should use a second variable to store the factorial result, you introduced it as `factorial`, the way that @danielku97 said is a good way to write a factorial since if you present 0 as input it will also give the correct result of 1. so a good code is:

```
factorial = 1;
for (int i = 1; i<=a; i++) 
{
    factorial *= i;
}
```

But lets say you insist of subtraction, the way you just tried to use, then you need to change the code like:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
if (a==1 || a==0){
    printf("1");
    return 0;
}

factorial = a;
for (int i = 1; i<a; i++) 
{
factorial *= (a - i)*factorial;
}
```

You can see that the code just got unnecessarily longer. An if included to correct the results for `1` and `0`. Also you need to make sure that `i` never become like `i =a` since in that case `a-i` will be equal to zero and will make the factorial result equal to zero.

I hope the explanations can help you on learning C and Algorithm faster.

Comment: thank you so much. I am always confused about for loop. This answer very helpful for me. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the input `a` rather than `factorial` and also wrong (undefined behaviour) because you are using `factorial` uninitialized. You simply need to use the `factorial` variable you declared.

```
int factorial = 1;
...

for (int i = 1; i<=a; i++) {
  factorial = i*factorial;
}
```

EDIT:

Also, be aware that C's `int` can only hold limited values. So, beyond a certain number (roughly after 13! if sizeof(int) is 4 bytes), you'll cause [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).
You may want to look at [GNU bugnum library](https://gmplib.org/) for handling large factorial values.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you your feedback :)

Comment: I don't see why modifying `a` would lead to undefined behaviour. Note that the term undefined behaviour is used in the C specification for operations where anything may happen. In this case the result is defined, although it is not the intended one.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is using your variable 'a' instead of the factorial variable and i, try something like this

```
factorial = 1;
for (int i = 1; i<=a; i++) 
{
    factorial *= i;
}
```

You must initialize your factorial to 1, and then the for loop will keep multiplying it by 'i' until 'i' is greater than 'a'.